# Script not logging to log file. Why?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have an `expect/Tcl` script as part of my bash script that logs into a remote router. Now, for testing purposes I am trying to handle the issue of time-out's. My problem is that the expect/Tcl script is not logging to my log file, and when it does it is logging everything the SSH connection is printing to my prompt which is not what I want.

Here's my expect script:

```
/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
    set timeout 5
    set send_human {.1 .3 1 .05 2}
    set myStamp [exec date +\[%d\/%m\/%Y\ \%T\]]

    set log_file ~/mylogfile.log

    spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "me\@$1"

    expect {
        "password: " { send -h "mypassword\r" }
        "No route to host" { exit 1 }
        timeout { send_log "\$myStamp Timed out to $1\n"]; exit 1 }
    }

    send -h "reboot in 1\r"
    sleep 1
    send -h "exit\r"
    expect eof
EOF
```

Please bear in mind that this is part of a function within my bash script that is passed the router name, hence the argument `$1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `log_file` **command**, not set a log_file *variable*

```
log_file ~/mylogfile.log
```

Other notes:

- Tcl has a very nice builtin command to handle time, don't need to call out to date:

  ```
  set myStamp [clock format [clock seconds] -format {[%d/%m/%Y %T]}]
  ```
- the <kbd>@</kbd> character is not special in Tcl/expect and does not need to be escaped:

  ```
  spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "me@$1"
  ```

---

As noted, `log_file` logs a *transcript of the session*. Just to log specific messages, you can use plain Tcl:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF

    proc log_msg {msg {to_stdout no}} {
        set log_line "[timestamp -format {[%Y-%m-%d %T]}] \$msg"
        set fh [open ~/mylogfile.log a]
        puts \$fh \$log_line
        close \$fh
        if {\$to_stdout} {puts \$log_line}
    }

    # ...
    expect {
        "No route to host" {
            log_msg "No route to host" yes
            exit 1 
        }
        timeout { log_msg "Timed out to $1"]; exit 1 }
    }

    # ...
EOF
```

This opens and closes the log for each message, which adds a bit of overhead. If milliseconds are important, open the log in the global scope, and use the global variable holding the file hendle in the log_msg proc.

Comment: BTW - does this log file require closing?

Comment: No, when expect exits, it will close its open file handles.

Comment: OK. This works, however I still have the issue of everything going to my log file such as all the SSH output which shows what is going on. Would this be solved by switching back and to `log_user 0` and `log_user 1`?

Comment: Is it only the timeout message that you want to log?

Comment: That's right, yes. Also, I'll be duplicating the line to output to the log in the no route to host as well.

Comment: Thanks. Though this proc is giving an `premature end of expression` error on the final `if {$to_stdout} {puts \$log_line}` line.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so concerned in this case about switching to `stdout` so I've deleted that line. Works well. Though for completeness you might want to re-edit your code for the benefit of future users.